# Custom Numeric Format Strings: Dynamic Decimal Point

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to format a double in C# such that it uses the thousand separator, and adds digits upto 4 decimal places.

This is straight forward except that I dont want to have the decimal point if it is an integer. Is there a way to do this using the custom numeric format strings rather than an if statement of tenary operator?

Currently I have:

```
string output = dbl.ToString(dbl == (int)dbl ? "#,##0" : "#,##0.####");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is not any built-in format string for this. Your current solution is the best way to accomplish this.

MSDN lists both the [standard numeric format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) and [custom numeric format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx), so you should be able to see for yourself that none directly matches your needs.

Comment: No problem. And yeah, if you want to make the method more convenient, I suggest you just wrap it into an extension method.

Comment: This is incorrect. The OP's second format string, `#,##0.####`, does exactly what they require.

Comment: @Luke: Take a closer look before commenting. That format string will format 2.34 and 2.34 for example, which is not whast the OP wants.

Comment: @Noldorin: I'm not sure what you meant in your comment. Can you elaborate? As far as I can tell that format string matches the requirements in the question.

Comment: @Luke: As I see it, if the number is integral, he wants to display no decimal points, whereas is the number is non-integral, he wants to display exactly 4 decimal points (no more, no less).

Comment: @Noldorin: I interpreted the "up to 4 decimal places" to mean 0, 1, 2, 3 or 4 places, but no more. Besides, using that second format string on its own generates *exacty the same output* as using the OP's ternary expression. *If* the ternary expression does produce the correct output, then so will the format string alone, so why not just use that?

Comment: @Luke: Yeah, you have a point there. I was presuming he actually wanted the second format string to be `#,##0.0000`. We need some clarification here from the OP I think.

Answer (score 8):

I believe your second format string of "#,##0.##" should be exactly what you want -- the # format character is a placeholder that will NOT display zeros.

If you had "#,###.00" then you *would* get trailing zeros.

test code:

```
double d = 45.00;
Console.Writeline(d.ToString("#,##0.##"));
```

Gives output of "45".  Setting d to 45.45 gives output "45.45", which sounds like what you're after.

So you had the answer after all! ;)